# iOS swift post реез request with binary body

Tags: ios, swift

I need to send an array of bytes to the server and receive another array of bytes in response, but the response comes

```
Status Code: 400, Headers {
     "Content-Type" = (
         "text / html; charset = UTF-8"
     );
}
```

my code

```
    let byteArray: [UInt8] = [UInt8](arrayLiteral: 0x05, 0x00, 0x07, 0x04, 0x00)
    let arrData = Data(byteArray)
    let requestURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.4.1/")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    request.setValue("application/octet-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue(String(arrData.count), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.httpBody = arrData
    var task = session.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
        print("DATA \(data ?? Data()) RESPONSE \(response) ERROR \(error)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: A 400 error means your request was bad but doesn't specify why. Since you're running your server locally you should check the logs to see why the request is not being accepted.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez my server is iot device

Answer (score 0):

Can't see why it does not work, but the first thing I would do is a simple local server that logs what it receives, and simulates what the device is supposed to send, to avoid mixing potential problems from everywhere.